# Passing constructor arguments in routing yml file in Symfony

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, yaml

I'm having some problems trying to call a route in my Symfony2 project as the controller I'm pointing to requires parameters (namely a username and password) in order to instantiate.

Here's the situation:

I'm integrating Kashflow into my project, and one of the things I need to do is to be able to send invoice payments from my CRM to the Kashflow account. When the "Push Payment" button is clicked, it runs an ajax call which sends the required data to a method called prepareInvoicePayment() in my Kashflow controller and, for testing purposes, simply returns the request so I can see what comes back.

My ajax:

```
$('.push-kashflow-payment').on('click', function(e) {
        var answer = confirm('Are you sure?');
        var invoiceID = $(this).attr('id').split("_")[0];
        var accountID = $(this).attr('id').split("_")[1];
        var method = 2;
        var amount = $(this).parent().parent().find('.amount').html();

        if (answer) {
            $.post('/kashflow-push-payment', { invoiceID: invoiceID, method: method, accountID: accountID, amount: amount  }
            ).done( function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        }

        e.preventDefault();

        return false;
    });
```

The problem:

MY routing file has the following entry:

```
app_push_kashflow_payment:
    path: /kashflow-push-payment
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Kashflow:prepareInvoicePayment }
```

But the Kashflow class requires a username and password to be passed to the constructor:

```
function __construct($user, $pass)
    {
        // Set the username and password
        $this->username = $user;
        $this->password = $pass;

        // Hide some simple XML errors we dont want to see
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    }
```

When the ajax request is sent to the controller, I get the following error returned:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for
>   AppBundle\Controller\KashflowController::__construct()

So, my question is, how can I pass these values in my routing file? Is this even the way to do it? If possible I'd rather set my username and password in my parameters.yml file and then reference that - but either way I need to be able to pass these parameters in order for the call to work.

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Use dependency injection and services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define you controller as service: [How to Define Controllers as Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) and pass all the arguments in the service definition config.